# UITableViewCell Background stretching

Tags: swift, uitableview, background

I have a problem in Swift with UITableViewCell background image. Let's say that it shows quite fine one iPhone5 but on iPhone 6Plus it is stretch and thus it looks bad. This is probably due to Aspect fill or something which I really couldn't manage to change and achieve what I want so would be the best if someone could poke sample code I am providing as well as image how it should look, so anyone can check it out and maybe give me some hint or tip or sample code or even fixed demo version. 
So here it is:

[image]

Note that on left side there is a curve (like half a circle) around right side of icon. On bigger phones or tablet, that curve gets super stretch thus completely destroying the look.

[Demo code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nwlrRuxLazOXNQTXI5SDVGd00/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks all in advance for any help. I am pretty stuck with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stretch an image while preserving the aspect ratio of a portion of that image using slicing. Xcode offers a graphical interface for doing this. The idea is that you decide what parts of the image are allowed to stretch and which aren't.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html